# How to use trained caret object to predict on new data (not used while training)?

Tags: r, r-caret, ensemble-learning

I am using `caret` package to train random forest model on training dataset. I have used 10-fold cross validation to get an object say `randomForestFit`. Now I would like to use this object to predict on new data set say `test_data`. I also want to get the respective class probabilities. How would I do that?

I have been using `extractProb` function as follows :

```
extractProb(randomForestFit, textX = test_data_predictors, testY = test_data_labels)
```

But it's giving me unexpected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `extractProb` help page example, you need to wrap the model in a list:

```
knnFit <- train(Species ~ ., data = iris, method = "knn", 
                trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))

rdaFit <- train(Species ~ ., data = iris, method = "rda", 
                trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))

predict(knnFit)
predict(knnFit, type = "prob")

bothModels <- list(knn = knnFit,
                   tree = rdaFit)

predict(bothModels)

extractPrediction(bothModels, testX = iris[1:10, -5])
extractProb(bothModels, testX = iris[1:10, -5])
```

So the following should work:

```
extractProb(list(randomForestFit), textX = test_data_predictors, testY = test_data_labels)
```

**edit:**

And yes, the preprocessing will be used. From the [documentation](http://topepo.github.io/caret/training.html#pred):

> These processing steps would be applied during any predictions
>   generated using predict.train, extractPrediction or extractProbs (see
>   details later in this document). The pre-processing would not be
>   applied to predictions that directly use the object$finalModel object.

Comment: Josh, I am able to run it and getting results. But my question is, whether the command I have shown does the same preprocessing on test data as well, and then apply prediction?

Comment: You are probably better off just using `predict(randomForestFit, test_data_predictors)`. The `extractPrediction` and `extractProb` functions were designed to be used with multiple models at once.